# Try/catch block in an infinity loop to print out something, if there is an infinity loop

Tags: java, loops, try-catch, infinite, try-catch-finally

this is my code (which is an infinity while loop. I should implement a try/catch block here, so that it stops, because it's going to infinity. My professor says we should implement a 'OutOfMemoryError', but I'm not sure how. It still goes to infinity in my case and ignores my try/catch block.

```
public class Infinite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myArray = { 2, 6, 8, 1, 9, 0, 10, 23, 7, 5, 3 };
 
            int length = myArray.length;
            int i = length;
            while (i < length + 6) {
                i--;
                System.out.println("hi");
            }
            System.out.println(" There is an error, it keeps on giving hi; ");
            System.exit(0);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is what i did: (with this i still get an infinity loop.

```
public class Infinite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myArray = { 2, 6, 8, 1, 9, 0, 10, 23, 7, 5, 3 };
        
        try {
            int length = myArray.length;
            int i = length;
            while (i < length + 6) {
                i--;
                System.out.println("hi");
            }
        
        } finally {
            System.out.println(" There is an error, it keeps on giving hi; ");
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not an infinite loop. You will have an [overflow](https://www.baeldung.com/java-overflow-underflow) and the condition will become false. Try removing the print to make the loop faster and you will see it will stop. In any case it will never throw an OutOfMemory exception anywhere. Can you post the actual assignment and question?

Comment: Write an application which contains an infinite while loop and use a try/catch block to catch the above-mentioned error (oome).  In order to do this, you need to fill the memory, for example by creating too many objects.

Comment: I'm a little confused? How is this not an infinity loop? Because it keeps on printing hi the entire time with no stop. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you wait enough, it will eventually stop. Remove the printing hi for a faster conclusion. Check the link on what's an integer overflow for why it will stop.

Comment: If you want an infinite loop you can just write `while(true)`. If you want it to throw an OOM you will have to allocate objects on each loop and keep a reference to them (for example using a list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is thrown when the Java VM cannot allocate an object because it´s out of memory. No more memory could be made by the garabage collector.
-> Trying to process to much data or eighter holding an object too long.
This code throws this error:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Heap {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[10000000 * 1000000];
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at Heap.main(Heap.java:8)
```

Read more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-outofmemoryerror-exception-java/